# How to select one field and delete all others QGIS graphical modeler

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

In the Graphical Modeler in QGIS I have the `algorithm` to `Drop Fields`, which you select the fields you want to drop:

[image]

However, the vector layer I'm using has many fields but I just need one in the end.
I'm wondering if there's any way to trick that in order for the user to just select this one field as an `Input` and all the others will be deleted automatically.

---

EDIT:
Ass suggested by @Erik, I used `refactor fields` but with that I'm  not able to get the input value from the user.

I have an input called "Field to Keep" where the user selects the field to be kept. However when I add this input to the Source Expression it understand as a string and all the rows of this column is filled up with the name of the field chosen by the user and not with the actual field value:

[image]

Comment: Nice, I didn't even read that you want the user to provide a column name before you edited.

Answer (score 3):

**Update:**

Another option would be to create a custom function (using the Function Editor):

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def all_fields(layer, feature, parent):
    provider = layer.dataProvider()
    field_names = [field.name() for field in provider.fields()]
    return field_names
```

And use this custom function in an expression like this:

```
array_remove_all(all_fields(@InputLayer), @InputField)
```

---

I'm aware of two options for this, but there might be (and hopefully are) nicer solutions.

**Option 1:**

Create two field inputs:

1. One input with all fields selected by default.
2. One input with the field which you want to keep.

Then use these two field inputs for the `Drop field(s)` algorithm as pre-calculated value with the following expression:

```
array_remove_all(@AllFields, @InputField)
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Option 2:**

Use one field input with all fields selected by default, and when running the model just deselect the field you want to keep:

[image]

[image]

[image]